# How to convert blob image into binarybase64 in java?

Tags: java, image, base64, arrays

I have image in blob format from DB , i am holding that blob image in byte array and  converting it to Binary Base64 format.

For encoding the blob to binary base 64 I am using below code,

```
 byte[] imageByte = getblob();//from DB
 byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64(imageByte);
```

is there any other way to do it or am doing it in right way please help me?

Comment: And what's your problem exactly?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct way of doing it.

Comment: i just want to confirm the way am doing is right,, because i need to pass the result ot webserivice request.

Answer (score 0):

if its not working than you can use

```
fileData.encode('base64')
```

this will solve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 
                   Base64.NO_WRAP);
```